# Auto dismiss a popup in kivy

Tags: python, class, popup, kivy

I need to dismiss the pop up after  finishing a function  in another class, or at least after specific time like (3 second) 
the pop up displaying loading gif image
to notify the user to wait for operating the functions

[loading image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zMo9.gif)

*******python******

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup 
from kivy.lang import Builder 
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

class progress(Popup):  
    pass 
class Func_(Screen):
# function
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("Try_.kv") 
class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return presentation

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

********KV File*********

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<Popup>:
    separator_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    background: "White.png"
    Button:
        id: btn
        disabled: True
        background_disabled_normal: "White.png"
        text: "Hello"
        Image:
            source: "Loading.gif"
            size: root.size

ScreenManagement:
    PopupBox:

<PopupBox>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Click"
            on_release:
                Factory.Popup().open()
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a function to dismiss the Popup message and use Clock.schedule_once to call that function. Please refer to the example below for details.

## main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.clock import Clock


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


class Progress(Popup):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Progress, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # call dismiss_popup in 2 seconds
        Clock.schedule_once(self.dismiss_popup, 2)

    def dismiss_popup(self, dt):
        self.dismiss()


class Func(Screen):
    # function
    pass


class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return ScreenManagement()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

## main.kv

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

<Progress>:
    separator_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    background: "White.png"
    Button:
        id: btn
        disabled: True
        background_disabled_normal: "White.png"
        text: "Hello"
        Image:
            source: "Loading.gif"
            size: root.size

<ScreenManagement>:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    Func:

<Func>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Click"
            on_release:
                Factory.Progress().open()
```

## Output

[image]